# Building GMP library on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, gmp, msys

I've builded gmp as shared library using msys, also created lib using VS utilites. But I've noticed, that there is no mpf_cmp_z declaration in automatic created header gmp.h.
In gmpxx.h this function presents in __gmp_binary_equal and __gmp_binary_less structures. Something was missed, when building gmp from sources? GMP 6.1.0.

Comment: I would assume that you have an older version lying around.

Comment: looks like something is wrong with using gmpxx.h under windows

Comment: If you don't find `mpf_cmp_z` in gmp.h, you are not looking at the gmp.h from GMP 6.1.0.